# build X11R7.7 from sources - in which order

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, compiling

Is there an automatic way to understand the order in which individual libraries of the X11R7.7 package should be built when I want to build all of `util`, `lib` and `xcb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in the order listed in the [X.Org build.sh script](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/util/modular/tree/build.sh) or by figuring out the dependency tree in the [X.Org jhbuild modules file](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/util/modular/tree/xorg.modules).

Note that X11R7.7 is nearly three years old now, and many of the modules have had newer versions, with security fixes, released since then, in the [X.Org individual releases archive](http://www.x.org/releases/individual/).